# ssh: id_rsa not accessible - how do I get it?

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm trying to make a ssh connection to a server with the following command,

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 12345 someusername@some.ip.add.ress
```

Debugging shows that permission was denied because id_rsa was not accessible, and in fact I don't have the file.

I'm not familiar with this id_rsa file.. Is this something I should request and receive from the server maintainer? Or is there a way to generate it?

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation... Learn how key authentication in the ssh protocol works. That will answer your question and you have to learn it anyway if you want to use it. In short: you have to generate a key for yourself and have "the administrator" accept the key.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it's not programming-related. Try asking on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to generate an SSH key pair on your computer. This will generate both a public and private key. The public key (denoted by a .pub) extension will need to be added to the server you are connecting to, normally in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, or via some web interface in the case of services like GitHub. The private key remains on your computer and is used in place of the `id_rsa` key you noted above within the `-i` switch.

You will be given the option to add a password and also to select a name for the key pair.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

More information can be found here (GitHub article, but not necessarily specific to GitHub): [GitHub: Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Comment: thank you for your help! I know this is a different question, but now I'm getting a "Roaming not allowed by server" message..any advice?